# RawBody not working for testingModule.createNestApplication(...) in nest.js

Tags: nestjs, supertest

I have trouble with rawbody webhook requests in my testinstance. In my normal instance which I setup with the following it works fine:

```
const app = await NestFactory.create(AppModule, {
      logger: logger,
      rawBody: true 
   });
```

In system test I setup my test instance like this

```
const testingModule: TestingModule = await Test.createTestingModule({
      imports: [AppModule],

   })
      .compile();

   const app = testingModule.createNestApplication({ rawBody: true });
```

and in my controller:

> public async webhook(@Req() req: RawBodyRequest, ...

the req.rawBody is undefined and thus validation fails. i checked and rawBody is indeed a valiud parameter of createNestApplication. So I wonder what I may be missing...

Or could this have sth. to do with supertest I use for testing (https://github.com/ladjs/supertest/issues/675 suggests that may be in issue in supertest but also indicates usage of express middleware settings may prevent it). Does anybody know how I can test properly if this is a nest.js or supertest issue?

Thanks
Tom